# Access MemberName/PropertyMap from ResolutionContext in an Automapper custom ValueResolver

Tags: automapper

I need to trace any complex (i.e. non-default) mappings in our project.

To achieve this, I'm using a custom value resolver, and publishing out a log event during resolution. As part of this message I'd like to know the destination member being mapped, which I was hoping to find in *source.Context.MemberName* - but this is always null.

**ValueResolver:**

```cs
public class Resolver : IValueResolver
{

    public event MappingEventHandler MappingEvent;
    public delegate void MappingEventHandler(MappingMessage m);

    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var src = (SourceDTO)source.Context.SourceValue;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.Status) && src.Status == "Alert")
        {
            var newValue = source.Value + " - Fail";
            var fieldName = source.Context.MemberName; //Always null

            MappingEvent(new MappingMessage(fieldName , newValue));

            return source.New(value, typeof(String));
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

**... and its usage:**

```cs
Resolver resolver = new Resolver();

//... subscribe to resolver events etc.

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDTO, Common>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ReferenceIdentifier
                , opt => opt.ResolveUsing<Resolver>()
                            .FromMember(src => src.Reference)
                            .ConstructedBy(() => resolver)
```

I can see in the Automapper code that MemberName only returns if the PropertyMap is non-null, and  since PropertyMap is null in this case, I'm not getting my MemberName back.

Is there a reason the PropertyMap isn't being defined in this here? There's a relevant candidate via *source.Context.TypeMap.GetPropertyMaps()*, but it's not being pushed into this context.

Any ideas? Perhaps there's a means of pulling the right PropertyMap out of the Context.TypeMap set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with the more recent Automapper build - looks like the problem has been resolved.

Version with issue: 2.1.266

Working version:  2.2.1

Also found it's a lot easier to use the following syntax to resolve from an existing instance:

```cs
Resolver resolver = new Resolver();

//... subscribe to resolver events etc.

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDTO, Common>()
                      .ForMember(dest => dest.ReferenceIdentifier
                                , opt => opt.ResolveUsing(resolver)
                                            .FromMember(src => src.Reference) )
```